# Убрать Nan при выводе в XML?

Tags: xml, pandas

Преобразовываю датафрейм в XML и после выполнения кода в итоговом XML Файле в некоторых значениях, **где должно быть пусто**, стоит значение NA или nan, как на примере ниже

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

и никак не могу побороть эту ошибку. Где то писали, что можно добавить код и все заработает

```
df = df.replace('None','')
df = df.replace('nan','')
```

Но у меня выводит ошибку: 'bool' object has no attribute 'to_numpy', с которой я не могу разобраться и считаю этот метод не совсем верным. Но рассматриваю и его за неимением лучшего, если получится понять в чем ошибка.

Так же в интернете предлагается использовать na_rep='' и это решение должно быть верное, но я не могу понять в каком месте мне нужно вставить эти буквы. Подскажите пожалуйста.

Ниже пример кода с вымышленным фреймом данных.

```
import pandas as pd

def to_xml(df, filename=None, mode='w'):
    def row_to_xml(row):
        xml = ['<Ad>']
        for i, col_name in enumerate(row.index):
            xml.append('  <{0}>{1}</{0}>'.format(col_name, row.iloc[i]))      
        xml.append('</Ad>')
        return '\n'.join(xml)
    res = '\n'.join(df.apply(row_to_xml, axis=1))

    if filename is None:
        return res
    with open(filename, mode) as f:
        f.write(res)

pd.DataFrame.to_xml = to_xml

df = pd.DataFrame({'Id': [4454, 4420, 1827],
           'Category': ['Хобби и отдых', 'Хобби и отдых', 'Хобби и отдых'],
           'Condition': ['Музыкальные инструменты', 'Музыкальные инструменты', 'Музыкальные инструменты'],
           'GoodsType': ['Для студии и концертов', 'Для студии и концертов', 'Для студии и концертов'],
           'AdType': ['Товар приобретен на продажу', 'Товар приобретен на продажу', 'Товар приобретен на продажу'],
           'Address': ['Москва', 'Москва', 'Москва'],
           'AllowEmail': ['Да', 'Да', 'Да'],
           'ContactPhone': ['+7 (111) 111-11-11', '+7 (111) 111-11-11', '+7 (111) 111-11-11'],
           'Condition': ['Новое', 'Новое', 'Новое'],
           'ManagerName': ['Name Shop', 'Name Shop', 'Name Shop'],
           'Title': ['name', 'name', 'name'],
           'Description': ['Текст объявления', 'Текст объявления', 'Текст объявления'],
           'Images': ['domein.ru', 'domein.ru', 'domein.ru'],
           'VideoURL': ['youtube.com', 'youtube.com', 'youtube.com'],
           'Price': [8000, 5676, 99200]})

df.loc[df['Price'] == 5676, 'Price'] = pd.NA

a = '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>\n<Ads formatVersion="3" 
target="Avito.ru">\n'
with open('foouty.xml', "w", encoding="utf-8") as h:
        h.write(a + df.to_xml())
```

Ну и в конце на всякий покажу, как должно быть.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Если вы можете запустить XSLT в качестве пост-обработки, очень легко удалить ненужные элементы XML.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Заменить `NA` можно, найдя их с помощью метода `isna`:

```
df.loc[df['Price'].isna(), 'Price'] = ''
```

В результате:

```
<Price></Price>
```

Comment: Да. помогло. Спасибо.